# Is it possible to not send messages for 2 people?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I made a discord bot and every time someone uses a command it replies to the command, and I am trying to make it work that if my friend and I send a command it wouldn't reply.

My friend and I are called SugarPancake and vordemolt on discord

this is the code:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');

 const client = new Discord.Client({ partials: ["MESSAGE", "CHANNEL", "REACTION"] });

const prefix = '-';

 const fs = require('fs');

 client.commands = new Discord.Collection();

const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands/').filter(file => 
file.endsWith('.js'));
for (const file of commandFiles) {
const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);

client.commands.set(command.name, command);
}




client.once('ready', () => {
console.log('YES is online');
client.user.setActivity(' You Shower', { type: "WATCHING" })
});



client.on('message', message => {

if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();
if (message.author.username == "SugarPancake" || message.author.username == 
 "vordemolt" || message.author.username == "malte" || message.author.username == 
  "Dr.Garbets") {
    if (command === 'comebw') {
        client.commands.get('comebw').execute(message, args);

    } else if (command == 'come') {
        client.commands.get('come').execute(message, args);
    }
    else if (command == 'mc') {
        client.commands.get('mc').execute(message, args);
    } else if (command == 'mute') {
        console.log(message.author.username);
        client.commands.get('mute').execute(message, args);
    } else if (command == 'unmute') {
        client.commands.get('unmute').execute(message, args);
    } else if (command == 'kick') {
        client.commands.get('kick').execute(message, args);


    }
    }
    client.on("message", (message) => {
    if (message.author.bot || !message.guild) return;
     if (message.content.toLowerCase() === ".test") {
    if (!message.member.roles.cache.some(r => r.name === "Admin")) 
        return message.channel.send("You don't have the required role to use this 
    command!");
      
    const roles = ["Admin"];
    if (!message.member.roles.cache.some(r => roles.includes(r.name)))
        return message.channel.send("You don't have the required role to use this 
    command");
  }
   });

    });
    client.on("message", async message => {
// white list
var usernames = ["SugarPancake", "vordemolt"];
if (usernames.includes(message.author.username) && message.content.startsWith("-")) {
    message.channel.send("We all love SugarPancake and vordemolt");
    message.channel.bulkDelete(1);

}
})
```

this isn't all of the code, there are all of the commands.

Comment: Those look like display names which are not unique on discord.  I think that you may have to use your actual user id name for this.  That's the name with the number after it that you have to use to friend someone or send DMs. (you probably don't want to show that name in a public place like StackOverflow though).

Comment: I think the best way for you to do this would be to create a role on Discord for users that should not be replied to, assign that role to you and your friend and then determine if a user has a role before trying to reply to them. Seems like the most scalable solution.

Answer (score 0):

You could essentially use an array to store the IDs of users that you don't want the bot to reply to, then use .includes().

It would look something like this

```js
client.on('message', message => {
 if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;
 const blacklistUsers = ['yourIDgoeshere', 'yourFriendsIDgoeshere'];
 if (blacklistUsers.includes(message.author.id)) return;
 // rest of your code
```

Make sure to replace the elements of the array with the respective user ID's

**How to get User ID**

Discord settings => appearance => developer mode (enable it) => right click a user => copy ID

Comment: This would throw a SyntaxError, it should be `if (blacklistUsers.includes("id")) return`

Comment: @AhmedBenn dang my bad, i left an unwanted parentheses thanks for pointing it out

Comment: where am I meant to add this?

Comment: @UriyahLiberman below this `if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;` add this line of code `const blacklistUsers = ['yourIDgoeshere', 'yourFriendsIDgoeshere'];
 if (blacklistUsers.includes(message.author.id)) return;`